# turning off hover for the parent li element while there is hover on another li element inside ul

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have an li element with an ul element and some li elements inside. Those li elements have `a` elements using href. One of these `a` elements has the same path as the li which contains the ul.

When I hover on these li element it also hovers the parent li of the ul. How can I change that without giving them different paths?

I have already tried setting "pointer-events: none" but it doesn't work. It disables all of the effect on the element and I want just to remove the hover.

```
.scroll-sidebar {
 padding-bottom: 6rem;
 } 
.collapse.in {
display: block;
}
.sidebar-nav { 
background: $sidebar; padding: 0; 
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
li {
  list-style: none;
  a {
    color: $sidebar-text;
    padding: 0.8rem 3.5rem 0.8rem 1.5rem;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    &.active,
    &:hover {
      color: $themecolor;
      i {
        color: $themecolor;
      }
    }
    &.active {
      font-weight: 500;
      color: $dark;
    }
  }
  ul {
    padding-left: 28px;
    li a {
      padding: 0.7rem 3.5rem 0.7rem 1.5rem;
    }
    li a.active {
      background: $light-info;
    }
    ul {
      padding-left: 1.5rem;
    }
  }
  &.nav-small-cap {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 1.4rem 1.4rem 1.4rem 2rem;
    color: $dark;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  &.nav-devider {
    height: 1px;
    background: $border;
    display: block;
    margin: 2rem 0;
  }
}
}  
>ul>li>a {
border-left: 3px solid transparent;
i {
  width: 2.7rem;
  font-size: 1.9rem;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: $sidebar-icons;
}
.label {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0.6rem;
}
&.active {
  font-weight: 400;
  background: $light-info;
  color: $themecolor-alt;
}
```

---

```
<li>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="{{ path('list_tests') }}" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="mdi mdi-creation"></i>
        <span class="hide-menu">Tests</span>
    </a>
    <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
        <li><a href="{{ path('list_tests') }}">Tests</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ path('list_test_data') }}">Data</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ path('list_application_tests') }}">Test Applications</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I want these two li elements with the same path to hover separately.

Comment: Please show the related CSS for your hover.

Comment: You can use a JavaScript event listener and use `e.stopPropagation()` so it doesn't bubble out to the container.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hover state for the UL as well, resetting the color:

```
ul ul&:hover { ... };
```